# subrepos - Does Mercurial's subrepositories can be used to push multiple project in a repository?

Tags: mercurial, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

I have 3 projects:

```
D:\Projects\ProjectA\src\packA
D:\Projects\ProjectB\src\packB
D:\Projects\ProjectC\src\packC
```

I want to store the 3 packages of these 3 projects in a same distant repository.

I tried to clone the 3 packages in the clone of my distant repository:

```
D:\mercurial\DistantRepo\packA
D:\mercurial\DistantRepo\packB
D:\mercurial\DistantRepo\packC
```

Then I declared these 3 packages as subrepositories in my .hgsub file:

```
packA = D:/Project/ProjectA/src/packA
packB = D:/Project/ProjectB/src/packB
packC = D:/Project/ProjectC/src/packC
```

I called the `hg add` and `hg commit` commands.

But when I try to push the files to my distant repository, the .hgsub and .hgsubstate files are pushed to my distant repository, but the following happen to my packages:

```
pushing to https://my.distant.repo
pushing subrepo packA to D:/Projects/ProjectA/src/packA
searching for changes
no changes found
pushing subrepo packB to D:/Projects/ProjectB/src/packB
searching for changes
no changes found
pushing subrepo packC to D:/Projects/ProjectC/src/packC
searching for changes
no changes found
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 1 changesets with 2 changes to 2 files
```

It seems I misunderstood how subrepositories work...

Does the use of subrepositories stick to my use case? How what I want to do may be done?

Answer (score 0):

## No changes found

```
pushing subrepo packA to D:/Projects/ProjectA/src/packA
searching for changes
no changes found
```

This means that there are no changesets in `packA` which are not already in `D:/Projects/ProjectA/src/packA`. This is OK if

- There is really no new stuff in `packA`
- you already pushed `packA` to `D:/Projects/ProjectA/src/packA`

If in doubt issue `hg outguing D:/Projects/ProjectA/src/packA` inside of the `packA` directory to get sure. This command should give no output(=nothing to send).

## Paths

These subrepos are pushed to `D:/Projects/Project[ABC]/src/pack[ABC]` since you gave mercurial these absolute urls in the .hgsub file. It might be better to change .hgsub to read like the following:

```
packA = packA
packB = packB
packC = packC

# You can also insert something like packA = ProjectA/src/packA, the point
# is to declare all subrepos as subdirectories of the main repo
```

and change the server so that it serves

- the original product at /
- ProjectA/src/packA at /packA
- ProjectB/src/packB at /packB
- ProjectC/src/packC at /packC

This is a [recommended pattern](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Use_.27trivial.27_subrepo_paths_where_possible), since you can easily have local mirror-clones of this repo, while you get trouble with relative and absolute URLs with local mirrors (it is possible, but cumbersome).

As a side note you might also consider to use a dependency-tracking outer repository ( called "[thin shell repository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Use_a_thin_shell_repository_to_manage_your_subrepositories)" in the hg wiki), which embeds your pack* repos as well as the product repo as subrepos, since than it is more clear where each piece of software belongs to.

**edit**

In mercurial you can have only one repository per product, and on the server on URL per repository. This means that you need to set up different remote repositories for your main product and the subrepos, since you can't store the content of different subrepositories along with the product repository.

There is the possibility to `hg pull -f` these different repositories into one, but I advice against this practice. After such a pull it is *very difficult* to navigate in the history of this repository, since the history of the different sources are mixed (for example the tip revision of this repo swaps between the different sources every time someone pushes into it). You should only use this method, when the different subrepos share some common history, but it is better to keep them separated when they have nothing in common.

Comment: The point is that my source projects are in D:\Projects\Project[ABC] and I would like only copies in D:\mercurial\DistantRepo.

When an original project updates, I would like the corresponding repor in the DIstantRepo directory to be updated by mercurial with the pull/update commands.

Then, I would like to pudh the content of the DItantRepo directory to my distant repo, where packages will be found as subdirectories of the root. How to do that?

Comment: I can't manage to reach my expectations.

I have a distant repo called http://myrepo

I have 3 distinct projects, each one with the corresponding distinct package D:/Projects/Project[ABC]/src/pack[ABC]

I would like to create a local repo in D:/Mercurial which contains **only** the 3 packages pack[ABC] and push all that in my distant repo.

My distant repo should show http://myrepo/pack[ABC] and the files in there shall reflect the changes I made in D:/Projects/Project[ABC]/src/pack[ABC]